# Is it allowed to activate the ability of multiple planeswalkers in a single turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I have more than one planeswalker (different planeswalkers) in play.

During my turn, am I allowed to use **both** of their '+' abilities? Or can I only use one planeswalker ability from one planeswalker during my turn?

Answer (score 8):

You can use all of them; one from each planeswalker.

Here is the rule that prevents you from using the same ability repeatedly on your turn:

> **606.3.** A player may activate a loyalty ability of a permanent they control any time they have priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of their turn, but only if no player has previously activated a loyalty ability **of that permanent** that turn.

Emphasis mine. It only cares that you haven't used an ability of the specific permanent that turn; you can use one from each planeswalker each turn.

Comment: Small note: "of that permanent" means that you can do things like exile and return the planeswalker or play a planeswalker with the same name (and sacrifice the one that you already activated the loyalty ability for) to allow you to use a loyalty ability multiple times in a turn.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can activate both. The [rules](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190125.txt) specify you can't activate a *loyalty ability* of the same planeswalker twice during a turn, but does not specify any restrictions about multiple planeswalkers:

> 606.3. A player may activate a loyalty ability of a permanent they control any time they have priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of their turn, but only if no player has previously activated a loyalty ability of that permanent that turn.